# Why the divs are not floating away using BootStrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My divs are not floating left like it should as I am using BootStrap Grid System so if I used 4 cols and then again the 2nd div should take the next 4 cols but instead it's going down in the same cols not in row?

```css
/*!
 * Venue Management System (Common CSS)
 * Author # Umair Shah Yousafzai
 * Author Email # nicefellow1234@gmail.com
 * Date # 14 Aug2017
 */

@font-face {
 font-family: MyriadPro-Regular;
 src: url(../fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf);
}
         
@font-face {
    font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
    src: url(../fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf);
}
         
@font-face {
    font-family: Quicksand-Light;
    src: url(../fonts/Quicksand-Light.ttf);
}
         
@font-face {
 font-family: Quicksand-Regular;
 src: url(../fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf);
}

body { 
 background-color: rgb(232,246,235);
 font-family: Quicksand-Light;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

ul li {list-style: none !important }
a { text-decoration: none !important }

.container {padding-top: 100px;}

.dashboard {
 border: 0.5px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 30px;
}

.dashboard-menu-item {
 padding: 60px 0px 60px 0px;
 color:white;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px; 
}

.menu-icon {
 font-size: 20px !important;
}


.item-bg-dark {
 background-color: rgb(37,80,87);
}

.item-bg-light {
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    
    
    <!-- Dashboard Horizontal Menu -->
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="dashboard-menu-item item-bg-dark col-sm-3">
         <i class="fa fa-sliders menu-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> YOUR DASHBOARD
        </div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="dashboard-menu-item item-bg-dark col-sm-3">
         <i class="fa fa-sliders menu-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> YOUR DASHBOARD
        </div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="dashboard-menu-item item-bg-dark col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
         <i class="fa fa-sliders menu-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> YOUR DASHBOARD
        </div>
      </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

   </div>
```

**Expected Output :**

[image]

Comment: Please mark if you found it helpful, so others can follow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `row class` in the provided example to parent element and also put bootstrap grid classes to the next element i.e `li`. Kindly check the updated code.

```css
/*!
 * Venue Management System (Common CSS)
 * Author # Umair Shah Yousafzai
 * Author Email # nicefellow1234@gmail.com
 * Date # 14 Aug2017
 */

@font-face {
 font-family: MyriadPro-Regular;
 src: url(../fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf);
}
         
@font-face {
    font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
    src: url(../fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf);
}
         
@font-face {
    font-family: Quicksand-Light;
    src: url(../fonts/Quicksand-Light.ttf);
}
         
@font-face {
 font-family: Quicksand-Regular;
 src: url(../fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf);
}

body { 
 background-color: rgb(232,246,235);
 font-family: Quicksand-Light;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

ul li {list-style: none !important }
a { text-decoration: none !important }

.container {padding-top: 100px;}

.dashboard {
 border: 0.5px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 30px;
}

.dashboard-menu-item {
 padding: 60px 0px 60px 0px;
 color:white;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px; 
}

.menu-icon {
 font-size: 20px !important;
}


.item-bg-dark {
 background-color: rgb(37,80,87);
}

.item-bg-light {
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    
    
    <!-- Dashboard Horizontal Menu -->
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ul class="row">
     <li class=" col-sm-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="dashboard-menu-item item-bg-dark">
         <i class="fa fa-sliders menu-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> YOUR DASHBOARD
        </div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li class=" col-sm-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="dashboard-menu-item item-bg-dark">
         <i class="fa fa-sliders menu-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> YOUR DASHBOARD
        </div>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li class=" col-sm-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="dashboard-menu-item item-bg-dark ">
         <i class="fa fa-sliders menu-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> YOUR DASHBOARD
        </div>
      </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following markup for your ul/li:

```
<ul class="row">
  <li class="col-4">  </li>
  <li class="col-4">  </li>
</ul>
```

Change the "col-4" to whatever bootstrap col-class(es) you need.